# Pandas crosstab normalize

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have this code:

```
pd.crosstab(cars.Origin,cars.Type)
```

And the output I get is:

[image]

I am trying to use normalize but it gives me an error.
Is it something that I am doing wrong, or is something wrong with the installation?

```
pd.crosstab(cars.Origin,cars.Type, normalize=True)
```

I get the below error. Please advise

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in eval(self, func, other, errors, try_cast, mgr)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get_result(other)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in <module>
     17 from pandas.core.computation.check import _NUMEXPR_INSTALLED
---> 18 from pandas.core.ops import roperator
     19 

ImportError: cannot import name 'roperator' from 'pandas.core.ops' (/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-d5b72ea5be76> in <module>
----> 1 pd.crosstab(cars.Origin,cars.Type, normalize=True)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py in crosstab(index, columns, values, rownames, colnames, aggfunc, margins, margins_name, dropna, normalize)
    495     aggregation function are passed.
    496 
--> 497     Parameters
    498     ----------
    499     index : array-like, Series, or list of arrays/Series

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py in _normalize(table, normalize, margins, margins_name)
    526 
    527     Returns
--> 528     -------
    529     DataFrame
    530         Cross tabulation of the data.

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py in <lambda>(x)
    514     margins_name : str, default 'All'
    515         Name of the row/column that will contain the totals
--> 516         when margins is True.
    517     dropna : bool, default True
    518         Do not include columns whose entries are all NaN.

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _combine_const(self, other, func, errors, try_cast)
   4777             values = index._values
   4778             if not isinstance(index, (PeriodIndex, DatetimeIndex)):
-> 4779                 if values.dtype == np.object_:
   4780                     values = lib.maybe_convert_objects(values)
   4781 

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in eval(self, **kwargs)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in eval(self, func, other, errors, try_cast, mgr)

/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in handle_error()

TypeError: Could not operate 428 with block values cannot import name 'roperator' from 'pandas.core.ops' (/opt/Anaconda/2018.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py)
```

Comment: What version of pandas is this? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: @CameronRiddell-- 0.23.4

Answer (score 0):

The following post suggests that the version of `pandas` used in your notebook might not be the one you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726283/13240220

Comment: If you can, try to systematically use the latest version of a package. Then, quite often, if you are using a deprecated method, the package will let you know about it.
However, if you use an old version of a package and you attempt to use a method from a later version, that older version you are using obviously cannot let you know that the method belongs to a newer version.

When you check the [GitHub repository of `pandas`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/0.25.x/pandas/core/ops), you see that the missing module `roperator` only appears from version `0.25.x`. You are using 0.23.4.